# How can I add a style class name onto my anchor element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I know how to use JavaScript to add an anchor element to my page, for example

```
var userName_a = document.createElement('a');
```

However, now I'd like to add a style name onto that element also, for example I tried

```
var userName_a = document.createElement('a class="normalLink"');
```

Which didn't work, and caused my JavaScript to stop running.

Which is the best way to add a style name to an element Iv'e created using JavaScript?

Comment: after you've created it, do something like `userName_a.className = 'normalLink';` to add a class - but if you want to add STYLE as you asked, use `userName_a.style` for example `userName_a.style.background = 'red';` or `userName_a.style.cssText = 'color:blue; width:40px; height:20px;';`

Answer (score 2):

The [createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) function takes only the name of the HTML tag you wish to create, nothing else.

You access the style(s) of an element by using [style property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), or adding/removing style classes either through the [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className), or [classList list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Style property

```
userName_a.style.background = "#FF0000";
userName_a.style["font-size"] = "20px";
```

className

```
userName_a.className = "active";
```

classList

```
userName_a.classList.add("active");
userName_a.classList.remove("active");
userName_a.classList.toggle("active");
```

Comment: classList isn't available on browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: @BlakeA.Nichols Its available on most browsers. And a shim for those that don't

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to be complete.  Also note that classList doesn't work with SVG elements (not that he asked about those just throwing it in)

Answer (score 2):

like this

```js
var userName_a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(userName_a);
userName_a.innerHTML='HELLO WORLD';
userName_a.style='color:red;background:yellow'
```

Answer (score 1):

The most consistent way is to use the setAttribute function:

```
var userName_a = document.createElement('a');
userName_a.setAttribute( 'class', 'normalLink' );
userName_a.setAttribute( 'style', 'color:blue;font-weight:bold;' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you just want to have a class name on the object, the simplest way to do that is to just assign a class name to the object after you create it:

```
var userName_a = document.createElement('a');
userName_a.className = "normalLink";
```

You can also just modify the style property directly too:

```
userName_a.style.color = "red";
userName_a.style.textDecoration = "none";
```